# Nokogiri doesn't work using css selector

Tags: css, ruby, nokogiri

My code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

PAGE_URL = "http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/1799/Fixtures/Spain-Almeria"

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(PAGE_URL))

CSS_SELECTOR = "a.match-link.match-report.rc"

links = page.css(CSS_SELECTOR)

puts links.length   # => RESULT = 0
puts links[0].text   # => RESULT = none
puts links[0]["href"] # => RESULT = ./read_stats.rb:15:in `<main>': undefined method     `text' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

The results should be:

```
1
Match Report
/Matches/738463/MatchReport
```

But my results are:

```
0
./read_stats.rb:15:in `<main>': undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

It doesn't work, and I dont see the problem...

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think that selector should match anything? Have you looked at the HTML that gets returned? Are you sure that the element you're looking for is returned in the HTML rather than being added by some JavaScript?

Comment: I test it with Firebug and it works. Also I test the complete selector in the ruby script ("html body div#layout-wrapper div#layout-content-wrapper div#layout-content-2col-left div#team-fixture-wrapper.ws-panel table#team-fixtures.grid.fixture tbody tr.item.alt td.toolbar.right a.match-link.match-report.rc") and this does not work.

Comment: As @muistooshort has mentioned, Firebug does not neccessarily inspect the HTML DOM that the server initially delivered. Javascript can alter the DOM at runtime and Firebug shows you only the current alteration. Try this: `curl http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/1799/Fixtures/Spain-Almeria | grep 'match-link'` (it yields 0 results)...

Comment: When you're scraping pages, don't look at what the browser is doing, look at the raw HTML that the server sends back. Browsers will adjust the HTML to ensure validity and they will run JavaScript that Nokogiri won't.

Comment: We need to see a minimal example of the HTML being parsed. Don't expect us to retrieve the entire page and trace through the tags. Instead of trying to use a long selector, start with the shortest CSS, then slowly add additional tags until you've located the problem. And, as said above, don't trust Firebug or the browser. Look at the HTML that Nokogiri gets via `open`.

Comment: The content is created with javascript, so this table doesn't exist. I found a solution, using selenium + phantomjs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to render the page before you can scrape it.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'nokogiri'

$browser = Watir::Browser.start "http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/1799/Fixtures/Spain-Almeria"

$page_html = Nokogiri::HTML.parse($browser.html)

$page_html.css("td[@class='toolbar right']").each do |me|
  print "#{me.count}\n#{me.text}\n#{me.css("a").map{|link| link['href']}[0]}\n\n"
end
```

Try out [watir.com](http://www.watir.com)

Comment: Perfect! Using selenium + phantomjs is the same logic. Render the page in a browser to load de js content.